# binding data to a dynamic select box

Tags: angular, angular-material

Actually, I am performing a READ operation in angular and I am trying to bind the data coming from the database to a dynamic select box to perform an update.

The data which I want to bind is in {{personaldetails?.gender1}} i.e the read value from the database. I only want to show this data in a select box so that the user can perform an update which is the later part.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ng-Model)]="{{personaldetails?.gender1}}" 
       formControlName="gender" #gender1>
      <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let gender1 of gender" [value]="gender1.value">
      {{gender1.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I guess I m not getting what you really want !!! please try to explain more,

Comment: the only thing is that I want to interpolate the data in a select box which is stored in {{personaldetails?.gender1}}. So that It will be easy for the user to edit if he/she want to edit.